# .scroll off to change the screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I resize image with jQuery scrolling only when the screen size is greater than or equal to 992px?

I've tried the following code, but it didn't work.

```js
jQuery(function () {
    /*Logo Resize*/
    jQuery(window).resize(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).width() < 992) {
            jQuery('#logo-img img').attr('src', 'imgs/min_logo.png');
        }
        if (jQuery(this).width() >= 992) {
            /*Logo Scroll*/
            jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() >= 250) {
                    jQuery('#logo-img img').attr('src', 'imgs/min_logo.png');
                }
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() < 250) {
                    jQuery('#logo-img img').attr('src', 'imgs/logo.png');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Binding `scroll` event handler on a `resize` event is a **mistake**. Why don't you use CSS Media Queries?

Comment: @Rodrigo Morgavi: care to share a fiddle, a jsfiddle..

Comment: I can use CSS Media Queries for scroll efect?

Comment: No, unfortunately, but you can leave the `resize` handling to CSS Media Queries.

Comment: I know that. The problem is when I turn off the scroll function.